# UNION 2 Select-queries with computed columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 4 simple tables containing GUIDs in a database.
The database schema looks like this:

[image: Database Schema]

I have created some example data.

```
CREATE TABLE `computermapping` (
  `ComputerMappingID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PrinterGUID` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `ComputerGUID` char(36) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `computermapping` (`ComputerMappingID`, `PrinterGUID`, `ComputerGUID`) VALUES
(43, 'a353199e-cd02-4fa6-904e-c172235abe9f', '87f44dc7-09e9-483c-935c-325b77ea4355'),
(44, '5549f63f-e02f-4685-a976-96b50c299bed', '87f44dc7-09e9-483c-935c-325b77ea4355'),
(80, 'a353199e-cd02-4fa6-904e-c172235abe9f', '4e392a05-e535-457f-abc3-3f22739aa5ca'),
(90, 'd2e9c5b9-43aa-4713-98e5-deb5e09e461b', '6bc91c0e-9aea-4847-895b-d8064e8feae5'),
(91, '5da046e3-4fb3-4ca5-89e8-239d81d6dc97', '6bc91c0e-9aea-4847-895b-d8064e8feae5'),
(92, '4b4a9288-1368-4ec7-a184-638d432d7d28', '5bec3779-b002-46ba-97c4-19158c13001f'),
(93, '5549f63f-e02f-4685-a976-96b50c299bed', '5bec3779-b002-46ba-97c4-19158c13001f'),
(94, '957b7233-e590-4e7d-aed6-aee0573fc3a8', '5bec3779-b002-46ba-97c4-19158c13001f'),
(95, '5106f1f7-068f-463f-9b76-7cc0ba017184', '5bec3779-b002-46ba-97c4-19158c13001f');

CREATE TABLE `computerdefaultprinter` (
  `ComputerGUID` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `PrinterGUID` char(36) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `computerdefaultprinter` (`ComputerGUID`, `PrinterGUID`) VALUES
('5bec3779-b002-46ba-97c4-19158c13001f', '4b4a9288-1368-4ec7-a184-638d432d7d28'),
('87f44dc7-09e9-483c-935c-325b77ea4355', 'a353199e-cd02-4fa6-904e-c172235abe9f'),
('6bc91c0e-9aea-4847-895b-d8064e8feae5', 'd2e9c5b9-43aa-4713-98e5-deb5e09e461b');

CREATE TABLE `usermapping` (
  `UserMappingID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PrinterGUID` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `UserGUID` char(36) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `usermapping` (`UserMappingID`, `PrinterGUID`, `UserGUID`) VALUES
(63, '4b4a9288-1368-4ec7-a184-638d432d7d28', 'd3cf699b-8d71-4dbc-92f3-402950042054'),
(64, 'a353199e-cd02-4fa6-904e-c172235abe9f', 'd3cf699b-8d71-4dbc-92f3-402950042054'),
(65, 'd2e9c5b9-43aa-4713-98e5-deb5e09e461b', '25c35cf5-ec20-4be5-a7f5-68f6fb93d192'),
(66, '5549f63f-e02f-4685-a976-96b50c299bed', '5ca9359d-5492-4b22-bd02-209f104e61d3');

CREATE TABLE `userdefaultprinter` (
  `UserGUID` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `PrinterGUID` char(36) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `userdefaultprinter` (`UserGUID`, `PrinterGUID`) VALUES
('d3cf699b-8d71-4dbc-92f3-402950042054', '4b4a9288-1368-4ec7-a184-638d432d7d28'),
('5ca9359d-5492-4b22-bd02-209f104e61d3', '5549f63f-e02f-4685-a976-96b50c299bed'),
('25c35cf5-ec20-4be5-a7f5-68f6fb93d192', 'd2e9c5b9-43aa-4713-98e5-deb5e09e461b');
```

Link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9e4ce

At first I want to query for all Printers that should get connected to a Computer. The Computer is identified by its ComputerGUID. (*in example: 5bec3779-...*)
I also want to know, which Printer will be the Default-Printer. A Computer can only have one Default-Printer.

I use the following query:

```
SELECT cm.PrinterGUID,
CASE 
 WHEN cp.PrinterGUID IS NULL THEN 0 
 ELSE 1 
END AS isDefaultPrinter
  FROM computermapping cm
  LEFT 
  JOIN computerdefaultprinter cp 
    ON cm.ComputerGUID = cp.ComputerGUID 
   AND cm.PrinterGUID = cp.PrinterGUID 
 WHERE cm.ComputerGUID = '5bec3779-b002-46ba-97c4-19158c13001f'
 ORDER 
    BY cm.PrinterGUID
```

I get the follwoing result, which is OK:

```
PrinterGUID                          | isDefaultPrinter
---------------------------------------------------------
4b4a9288-1368-4ec7-a184-638d432d7d28 | 1
5106f1f7-068f-463f-9b76-7cc0ba017184 | 0
5549f63f-e02f-4685-a976-96b50c299bed | 0
957b7233-e590-4e7d-aed6-aee0573fc3a8 | 0
```

.

Second I have the same for users:

```
SELECT usermapping.PrinterGUID,
CASE 
 WHEN userdefaultprinter.PrinterGUID IS NULL THEN 0 
 ELSE 1 
END AS isDefaultPrinter
FROM usermapping
LEFT JOIN userdefaultprinter ON usermapping.UserGUID = userdefaultprinter.UserGUID AND usermapping.PrinterGUID = userdefaultprinter.PrinterGUID 
WHERE usermapping.UserGUID = 'd3cf699b-8d71-4dbc-92f3-402950042054'
ORDER BY usermapping.PrinterGUID
```

Result:

```
PrinterGUID                          | isDefaultPrinter
---------------------------------------------------------
4b4a9288-1368-4ec7-a184-638d432d7d28 | 1
a353199e-cd02-4fa6-904e-c172235abe9f | 0
```

.

This is all OK. To simplify my program, I want to replace those 2 query's by a single SQL-query.
The desired result would look like this:

```
PrinterGUID                          | isComputerDefaultPrinter | isUserDefaultPrinter
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4b4a9288-1368-4ec7-a184-638d432d7d28 | 1                        | 1
5106f1f7-068f-463f-9b76-7cc0ba017184 | 0                        | 0
5549f63f-e02f-4685-a976-96b50c299bed | 0                        | 0
957b7233-e590-4e7d-aed6-aee0573fc3a8 | 0                        | 0
a353199e-cd02-4fa6-904e-c172235abe9f | 0                        | 0
```

The PrinterGUID should be Unique in the result. Of course the User Default-Printer may not be the same as the Computer Default-Printer like in the example above.

**EDIT:**
Unfortunately my know-how in SQL is limited. As of my research using a UNION would be suitable to join two selects. I started to build up a query using the above example as base. This is the query I ended up with, but the result is not as desired.

```
SELECT computermapping.PrinterGUID,
CASE 
 WHEN computerdefaultprinter.PrinterGUID IS NULL THEN 0 
 ELSE 1 
END AS isComputerDefaultPrinter,
null AS isUserDefaultPrinter
FROM computermapping 
LEFT JOIN computerdefaultprinter ON computermapping.ComputerGUID = computerdefaultprinter.ComputerGUID AND computermapping.PrinterGUID = computerdefaultprinter.PrinterGUID 
WHERE computermapping.ComputerGUID = '5bec3779-b002-46ba-97c4-19158c13001f'

UNION

SELECT usermapping.PrinterGUID,
null AS isComputerDefaultPrinter,
CASE 
 WHEN userdefaultprinter.PrinterGUID IS NULL THEN 0 
 ELSE 1 
END AS isUserDefaultPrinter
FROM usermapping
LEFT JOIN userdefaultprinter ON usermapping.UserGUID = userdefaultprinter.UserGUID AND usermapping.PrinterGUID = userdefaultprinter.PrinterGUID 
WHERE usermapping.UserGUID = 'd3cf699b-8d71-4dbc-92f3-402950042054'
```

Could you please help me to solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: This seems straightforward enough, but I don't see how this is a useful result.

Comment: Incidentally, none of the significance of this problem is lost by using a sample id of '904e', say, instead of 'a353199e-cd02-4fa6-904e-c172235abe9f'

Comment: "I tried a UNION, but I had problems. I did not get it to work as desired."  We all tried UNION, but sorry, it "did not work "...... (sigh)      Please give some more info!, Thanks.

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: @forpas One host should be MySQL 5.7 and the other I currently use for testing is 10.4.17-MariaDB.

Comment: @Strawberry It may be because I am no native English speaker or the the lack of SQL know-how, but unfortunately I don't understand, what you wanted to tell me in your 2 comments.

Comment: 1. Your query returns a list of printers that may or may not have any relationship with a given computer and given user. I don't see how that's useful. 2. '904e' is more user-friendly/comprehensible than  'a353199e-cd02-4fa6-904e-c172235abe9f', where the user is me/us.

Comment: @Strawberry You are right - There was an additional table containing the Printers in between. This table has been outsourced. The Printers are stored in LDAP.

Comment: @Strawberry Yes - I could/should have shortend the GUIDs for better readability.

Comment: I still don't get it. Why is it useful to know that a printer is not the default printer of a given user/computer? It's like asking, 'For which firms does an employee not work?'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the key idea is to get the list of printers that you want:

```
select PrinterGUID
from ((select cm.PrinterGUID
       from computermapping cm
       where cm.ComputerGUID = '5bec3779-b002-46ba-97c4-19158c13001f'
      ) union -- to remove duplicates
      (select PrinterGUID
       from usermapping um
       where um.UserGUID = 'd3cf699b-8d71-4dbc-92f3-402950042054'
      )
     ) p;
```

Then you can use `exists` to see if these are the defaults:

```
select p.PrinterGUID,
       (exists (select 1
                from computerdefaultprinter cdp
                where cdp.PrinterGUID = p.PrinterGUID and
                      cdp.ComputerGUID = '5bec3779-b002-46ba-97c4-19158c13001f'
               )
       ) as is_computer_default,
       (exists (select 1
                from userdefaultprinter udp
                where udp.PrinterGUID = p.PrinterGUID AND
                      udp.UserGUID = 'd3cf699b-8d71-4dbc-92f3-402950042054'
               )
      ) as is_user_default
from ((select cm.PrinterGUID
       from computermapping cm
       where cm.ComputerGUID = '5bec3779-b002-46ba-97c4-19158c13001f'
      ) union -- to remove duplicates
      (select PrinterGUID
       from usermapping um
       where um.UserGUID = 'd3cf699b-8d71-4dbc-92f3-402950042054'
      )
     ) p;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a0f421d8c902030c96832a777708a413) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The performance of the query is somehow better, than the other ones. I need to test it out further with real data, to see if everything is alright.

Comment: When I open your fiddle and select a Microsoft SQL-Server, it does not work. Do you have an idea why? It is possible, that my application will use MS-SQL too in the future.

Comment: @Walhalla . . . They are different databases.  SQL Server doesn't support backticks and has different functions for GUIDs, to start with.

Comment: OK - I will take care of it in the future.

Comment: I have implemented this query in my application and tested it with real-life data.
It works like a charm and helped reducing and optimizing my program-code.
As measured this query performs better than the ones from the other answer.
I will choose it as answer.

Comment: Hi, I wanted to kindly ask if you would you be able to make this query working with Microsoft SQL-Server? Would you assist me, if I would create a new Question about it? Thank you!

Comment: @Walhalla . . . If you have a question about SQL Server, then ask a question about SQL Server.  This question is clearly about MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You need a FULL OUTER JOIN of the 2 queries, but since MySql does not support it you must simulate it with LEFT/RIGHT joins and UNION ALL:

```
SELECT t1.PrinterGUID PrinterGUID, 
       t1.isDefaultPrinter isComputerDefaultPrinter,
       COALESCE(t2.isDefaultPrinter, 0) isUserDefaultPrinter
FROM (
  SELECT cm.PrinterGUID, cp.PrinterGUID IS NOT NULL AS isDefaultPrinter
  FROM computermapping cm LEFT JOIN computerdefaultprinter cp  
  ON cm.ComputerGUID = cp.ComputerGUID AND cm.PrinterGUID = cp.PrinterGUID 
  WHERE cm.ComputerGUID = '5bec3779-b002-46ba-97c4-19158c13001f'
) t1 LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT um.PrinterGUID, up.PrinterGUID IS NOT NULL AS isDefaultPrinter
  FROM usermapping um LEFT JOIN userdefaultprinter up
  ON um.UserGUID = up.UserGUID AND um.PrinterGUID = up.PrinterGUID 
  WHERE um.UserGUID = 'd3cf699b-8d71-4dbc-92f3-402950042054'
) t2 ON t2.PrinterGUID = t1.PrinterGUID
UNION ALL
SELECT t2.PrinterGUID PrinterGUID, 
       COALESCE(t1.isDefaultPrinter, 0) isComputerDefaultPrinter,
       t2.isDefaultPrinter isUserDefaultPrinter
FROM (
  SELECT cm.PrinterGUID, cp.PrinterGUID IS NOT NULL AS isDefaultPrinter
  FROM computermapping cm LEFT JOIN computerdefaultprinter cp  
  ON cm.ComputerGUID = cp.ComputerGUID AND cm.PrinterGUID = cp.PrinterGUID 
  WHERE cm.ComputerGUID = '5bec3779-b002-46ba-97c4-19158c13001f'
) t1 RIGHT JOIN (
  SELECT um.PrinterGUID, up.PrinterGUID IS NOT NULL AS isDefaultPrinter
  FROM usermapping um LEFT JOIN userdefaultprinter up
  ON um.UserGUID = up.UserGUID AND um.PrinterGUID = up.PrinterGUID 
  WHERE um.UserGUID = 'd3cf699b-8d71-4dbc-92f3-402950042054'
) t2 ON t2.PrinterGUID = t1.PrinterGUID
WHERE t1.PrinterGUID IS NULL
ORDER BY PrinterGUID
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=160694c853285685fd6c50f03f9fa9e3).

In 10.4.17-MariaDB you could use CTEs to shorten the code:

```
WITH 
  cte1 AS (
    SELECT cm.PrinterGUID, cp.PrinterGUID IS NOT NULL AS isDefaultPrinter
    FROM computermapping cm LEFT JOIN computerdefaultprinter cp  
    ON cm.ComputerGUID = cp.ComputerGUID AND cm.PrinterGUID = cp.PrinterGUID 
    WHERE cm.ComputerGUID = '5bec3779-b002-46ba-97c4-19158c13001f'
  ),
  cte2 AS (
    SELECT um.PrinterGUID, up.PrinterGUID IS NOT NULL AS isDefaultPrinter
    FROM usermapping um LEFT JOIN userdefaultprinter up
    ON um.UserGUID = up.UserGUID AND um.PrinterGUID = up.PrinterGUID 
    WHERE um.UserGUID = 'd3cf699b-8d71-4dbc-92f3-402950042054'  
  )
SELECT t1.PrinterGUID PrinterGUID, 
       t1.isDefaultPrinter isComputerDefaultPrinter,
       COALESCE(t2.isDefaultPrinter, 0) isUserDefaultPrinter
FROM cte1 t1 LEFT JOIN cte2 t2 
ON t2.PrinterGUID = t1.PrinterGUID
UNION ALL
SELECT t2.PrinterGUID PrinterGUID, 
       COALESCE(t1.isDefaultPrinter, 0) isComputerDefaultPrinter,
       t2.isDefaultPrinter isUserDefaultPrinter
FROM cte1 t1 RIGHT JOIN cte2 t2 
ON t2.PrinterGUID = t1.PrinterGUID
WHERE t1.PrinterGUID IS NULL
ORDER BY PrinterGUID
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=6998c3879dcaaf447bfa24c08b9f3cde).

Results:

```
> PrinterGUID                          | isComputerDefaultPrinter | isUserDefaultPrinter
> :----------------------------------- | -----------------------: | -------------------:
> 4b4a9288-1368-4ec7-a184-638d432d7d28 |                        1 |                    1
> 5106f1f7-068f-463f-9b76-7cc0ba017184 |                        0 |                    0
> 5549f63f-e02f-4685-a976-96b50c299bed |                        0 |                    0
> 957b7233-e590-4e7d-aed6-aee0573fc3a8 |                        0 |                    0
> a353199e-cd02-4fa6-904e-c172235abe9f |                        0 |                    0
```

Comment: I have implemented the CTE-solution in my application. As for now it seems to be working pretty well :-) However far more complicated, than I thought. I am running some more test-cases now ...

Comment: @Walhalla The CTE solution will not work in MySql 5.7 because MySql supports CTEs since version 8.0+

Comment: Yes I understand. I maybe want to convert my application from pure MySQL to a more flexible solution, so I could use Microsoft SQL-Server as target too.
How about support for the CTE-solution on MS-SQL? You have an idea on that too?

Comment: @Walhalla SQL Server supports CTEs and FULL joins also, so there will be no need to simulate it. For this requirement I surely recommend SQL Server. Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=73b7ae1448928121e3e8b946d2957c66