# Incorrect syntax near "Exists" … - Convert Query from MySQL to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

My application uses a query that is working fine using a MySQL/MariaDB-Database.
I did modify my application to be more flexible and work with Microsoft SQL Server too.

Unfortunately the following query does **NOT work** using a SQL Server database:

```
select 
    p.PrinterGUID,
    (exists (select 1
             from computerdefaultprinter cdp
             where cdp.PrinterGUID = p.PrinterGUID and
                   cdp.ComputerGUID = '5bec3779-b002-46ba-97c4-19158c13001f')
    ) as is_computer_default,
    (exists (select 1
             from userdefaultprinter udp
             where udp.PrinterGUID = p.PrinterGUID and
                   udp.UserGUID = 'd3cf699b-8d71-4dbc-92f3-402950042054')
    ) as is_user_default
from 
    ((select cm.PrinterGUID
      from computermapping cm
      where cm.ComputerGUID = '5bec3779-b002-46ba-97c4-19158c13001f'
     ) union -- to remove duplicates
     (select PrinterGUID
      from usermapping um
      where um.UserGUID = 'd3cf699b-8d71-4dbc-92f3-402950042054')) p;
```

Running this query throws an error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'exists'

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio returns the following in German:

[image: SSMS Error]

I have created a SQL Fiddle with some example data: [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5fb718/1)

If necessary, more background-information is available here: [UNION 2 Select-queries with computed columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65548379/union-2-select-queries-with-computed-columns)

Is it possible to modify this query to work in both MySQL and SQL Server?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can't start a column's expression with `EXISTS`. What do you want, or not want, to be displayed when the `EXIST` returns true/false?

Comment: Hi @Larnu , the result should look exactly like it does with MySQL. Look at this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5fb718/4

Comment: @Larnu Oh for the missing `BOOLEAN` type. And the `ANY()` aggregate. And the `IS` comparator. All of which exists under the hood

Comment: Maybe we'll see it in SQL Server 2022, @Charlieface ;)

Comment: @Larnu 2122 at the rate we're going. How long has the tally table request been open for??

Comment: At least you can easily build those yourself, @Charlieface  . Though, having a built in tally  might stop people using an rCTE for such tasks. >_< But we're off topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The literal translation of your query would be the following:

```sql
select 
    p.PrinterGUID,
    CASE WHEN exists (select 1
                      from computerdefaultprinter cdp
                      where cdp.PrinterGUID = p.PrinterGUID and
                            cdp.ComputerGUID = '5bec3779-b002-46ba-97c4-19158c13001f')
         THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as is_computer_default,
    CASE WHEN exists (select 1
                      from userdefaultprinter udp
                      where udp.PrinterGUID = p.PrinterGUID and
                            udp.UserGUID = 'd3cf699b-8d71-4dbc-92f3-402950042054')
         THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as is_user_default
from (select cm.PrinterGUID
      from computermapping cm
      where cm.ComputerGUID = '5bec3779-b002-46ba-97c4-19158c13001f'
      union -- to remove duplicates
     select PrinterGUID
      from usermapping um
      where um.UserGUID = 'd3cf699b-8d71-4dbc-92f3-402950042054') p;
```

Notice the use of a `CASE` expressions to determine the value of the column for when the `EXISTS` evaluates to `true` or not.

Comment: For now this was the last puzzle-piece to get my application working with MS-SQL.  
Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just try out the following query. You don't need to use exists like this in sql server. Instead filter out the rows at the end  using `is_computer_default` or `is_user_default`

```
select p.PrinterGUID,
       (select 1
                from computerdefaultprinter cdp
                where cdp.PrinterGUID = p.PrinterGUID and
                      cdp.ComputerGUID = '5bec3779-b002-46ba-97c4-19158c13001f')
       as is_computer_default,
       (select 1
                from userdefaultprinter udp
                where udp.PrinterGUID = p.PrinterGUID AND
                      udp.UserGUID = 'd3cf699b-8d71-4dbc-92f3-402950042054'
               ) as is_user_default
from ((select cm.PrinterGUID
       from computermapping cm
       where cm.ComputerGUID = '5bec3779-b002-46ba-97c4-19158c13001f'
      ) union -- to remove duplicates
      (select PrinterGUID
       from usermapping um
       where um.UserGUID = 'd3cf699b-8d71-4dbc-92f3-402950042054'
      )
     ) p;
```

Comment: This *assumes* that the OP's subqueries only return 1 row.

Comment: Ignore my edit, editted the wrong answer. (Whoops!)